# Regex to match (French) numbers

Tags: python, regex, numbers

I'm trying to find a simple (not perfect) pattern to recognise French numbers in a French text. French numbers use comma for the Anglo-Saxon decimal, and use dot or space for the thousand separator. `\u00A0` is non-breaking space, also often used in French documents for the thousand separator.

So my first attempt is:

```
number_pattern = re.compile(r'\d[\d\., \u00A0]*\d', flags=re.UNICODE)
```

... but the trouble is that this doesn't then match a single digit.

But if I do this

```
number_pattern = re.compile(r'\d[\d\., \u00A0]*\d?', flags=re.UNICODE)
```

it then picks up trailing space (or NBS) characters (or for that matter a trailing comma or full stop).

The thing is, the pattern must both START and END with a digit, but it is possible that these may be the SAME character.

How might I achieve this? I considered a two-stage process where you try to see whether this is in fact a single-digit number... but that in itself is not trivial: if followed by a space, NBS, comma or dot, you then have to see whether the character after **that**, if there is one, is or is not a digit.

Obviously I'm hoping to find a solution which involves only one regex: if there is only one regex, it is then possible to do something like:

```
doubled_dollars_plain_text = plain_text.replace('$', '$$')
substituted_plain_text = re.sub(number_pattern, '$number', doubled_dollars_plain_text)
```

... having to use a two-stage process would make this much more lengthy and fiddly.

***Edit***

I tried to see whether I could implement ThierryLathuille's idea, so I tried:

```
re.compile(r'(\d(?:[\d\., \u00A0]*\d)?)', flags=re.UNICODE)
```

... this seems to work pretty well. Unlike JvdV's solution it doesn't attempt to check that thousand separators are followed by 3 digits, and for that matter you could have a succession of commas and spaces in the middle and it would still pass, which is quite problematic when you have a list of numbers separated by ", ". But it's acceptable for certain purposes... until something more sophisticated can be found.

I wonder if there's a way of saying "any non-digit in this pattern must be on its own" (i.e. must be bracketed between two digits)?

Comment: Make everything after the first digit optional?

Comment: Brilliant! Merci beaucoup.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille I had a try at this - see edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very much inspired by JvdV's answer, I suggest this:

```
number_pattern = re.compile(r'(\d{1,3}(?:(?:[. \u00A0])?\d{3})*(?:,\d+)?(?!\d))',  flags=re.UNICODE)
```

... this makes the thousand separator optional, and also makes thousand groups optional. It restricts the thousand-separator to 3 possible characters: dot, space and NBS, which is necessary for French numbers as found in practice.

PS I just found today that in fact Swiss French-speakers appear sometimes to use an apostrophe (of which there are several candidates in the vastness of Unicode) as a thousand separator.

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
\d{1,3}(?:[\s.]?\d{3})*(?:,\d+)?(?!\d)
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/hf8cn6/1)

- `\d{1,3}` - 1-3 digits.
- `(?:` - Open 1st non-capture group:

  - `[\s.]?` - An optional whitespace or literal dot. Note that with unicode `\s` should match `\p{Z}` to include the non-breaking whitespace.
  - `\d{3}` - Three digits.
  - `)*` - Close 1st non-capture group and match 0+ times.
- `(?:,\d+)?` - A 2nd optional non-capture group to match a comma followed by at least 1 digit.
- `(?!\d)` - A negative lookahead to prevent trailing digits.

Comment: I have yet to double-check this properly, but this looks perfect... with checking that "post-thousand-separator" digit-groups are in groups of 3, it seems. Fantastic, thanks! Just one thing: a tab character (for example) would never be found (unless a typo) used as a thousand separator. But this is a very minor quibble.

Comment: Sorry, I should also have mentioned that numbers don't *always* use any kind of thousand separator. Your regex divides up a number like 78155 into two numbers. No doubt there is a trade-off between comprehensiveness of the solution and finding something which will reject "anomalous" numbers.

Comment: @mikerodent, please have another try and let me know.

Comment: Hi, had a go with the latest version ... it seems to split "33.456" into ["33", ".", "456"]. Whereas that "." there should be interpreted as a thousand separator.

Comment: @mikerodent, a 2nd edit done.